# Creating fileset from subfolder with dynamic foldername

Tags: ant

i want to create a fileset for deployment via SCP. So far, so good, files are being deployed, BUT:

I only want to deploy files and subfolders of a folder with a dynamic name.

My directory tree is:

```
Source Files 
     |_ _target
           |_ <timestamp>-package
                  |_ css
                  |_ img
                  |_ js
                  |_ index.php
    |_ css
    |_ scss
    |_ img
    |_ config.rb
    [...]
```

I only want to deploy the files and subfolders of

```
_target | <timestamp>-package
```

so I declared the fileset like

```
<fileset id="fileset:deployment" dir="${basedir}/_target">
    <include name="**/**" />
</fileset>
```

As you see, the subfolder of "_target" has a dynamic name, because it contains a timestamp (it gets created with a different ant target). 
SCP now deploys the whole folder "timestamp-package", but I want to deploy ONLY the files and subfolders IN there. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably several ways to do this.  I'm assuming you have only one `<timestamp>-package` directory present at build time, as otherwise you would have ambiguity.

Here's one method.  Use a `<dirset>` task to identify the correct parent directory for your `<fileset>`:

```
<dirset id="src.dir" dir="_target">
    <include name="*-package" />
</dirset>
```

Then use that as part of the `dir` attribute of your `<fileset>`:

```
<fileset id="fileset:deployment" dir="_target/${ant.refid:src.dir}">
    <include name="**/**" />
</fileset>
```